# Attempting for loop with if-thn statement so that my desired value is surpassed by the value in the for loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

I'm working with a program so that it will be able to take a two values, and multiply the difference by the first power of ten above the sum and then add the sum.  So for 5 and 3, it would be 2 * 10 + 8 = 28.  This only works when the sum < 10.  I am wondering if anybody can help to make the else portion of the if-then-else statement to work so than one where 9 and 1 and other values can be input so then the other half of the program will work.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class StrangeCalculation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the first number?");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the second number?");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        int min = Math.min(num1, num2);
        int max = Math.max(num1, num2);
        int sum = min + max;
        int diff = max - min;
        int a = 1;
        if (sum < Math.pow(10, a + 1)) {
            int strangeValue = (int) (Math.pow(10, a) * diff + sum);
            System.out.println("The value is:  " + strangeValue);
        }
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i = 10 * i) {
                //Loop until the sum value can be exceeded
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple implementation with the main logic statement as,

```
double strangeValue = (Math.pow(10, (sum + "").length()) * diff + sum);
```

So, your program is,

```
public class StrangeCalculation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the first number?");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the second number?");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        int min = Math.min(num1, num2);
        int max = Math.max(num1, num2);
        int sum = min + max;
        int diff = max - min;

        // Main logic
        double strangeValue = (Math.pow(10, (sum + "").length()) * diff + sum);
    }
}
```